# installing a specific version of vtk using pip

Tags: python, linux, pip, vtk

I am trying to install vtk version 7.2 on python 2.7 (linux).

I used:
pip install vtk==7.1.1

But I get:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement vtk==7.2 (from versions: 8.1.0, 8.1.1, 8.1.2)

Can someone help me understand why it is only allowing me to install newer versions?

Answer (score 2):

There's no PyPI wheel available for `vtk` version 7.2. [Here](https://pypi.org/project/vtk/#history) are the available wheels.

For installation of older versions of `vtk` on Linux, refer [here](http://kazenotaiyo.blogspot.com/2010/06/installing-vtk-in-ubuntu-and-making.html?m=1).

Comment: hey, it does seem to have earlier versions: https://vtk.org/download/. I'm fixing it to version 7.1.1 which gives me the same error

Comment: VTK does not have Python wheels available for 2.7 on Windows due to C++ 11 incompatibilities or something. Can you try Python3?

Comment: I can't unfortunately. But I am using linux, should it be available?

Comment: I have added a link to my answer that can help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Able to install vtk on python3.8 directly from the source.
Follow below commands, it is a bit time taking to build the wheel but would definitely install vtk.
Download the version you want to install, in my case i installed the latest 9.1.0 from [enter link description here](https://vtk.org/download/)

```
    //extract the downloaded file.
    mkdir VTK_BUILD
    cd VTK_BUILD
    cmake -GNinja -DVTK_WHEEL_BUILD=ON -DVTK_WRAP_PYTHON=ON {vtk source path}
    ninja
    python3 setup.py bdist_wheel
```

copy path to VTK_BUILD
add vtk build paths to the bashrc file to set the path.

```
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:{copied build path}
   export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:{copied build path}
```

This should install vtk.

source link:
https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/-/blob/master/Documentation/dev/build.md#building-vtk